# "Home" breadcrumb text is not translated in French using Loco translate plugin WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to translate the Breadcrumb text in any other language using Loco translate WordPress plugin.

In admin panel it shows me exact translation but the changes not reflect on front end, please check this image:

[image]

Inside Theme-> language I have set "Home" breadcrumb value but the changes not appears on front end.
Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.